# SELECT by related records?

Tags: sql, select, many-to-many, relational-database

I need to find record in SQL by exact array of related records. This is my sample schema:

#### Posts table

```
==========
posts
==========
id | text
----------
1  | Hello
----------
2  | Hello
----------
3  | Hello
```

#### Users table

```
==========
users
==========
id | name
----------
1  | Vova
----------
2  | Ilya
----------
3  | Ivan
----------
3  | Peter
```

#### junction table

```
==========
userposts
==========
UserID | PostID
---------------
1      | 1
---------------
2      | 1
---------------
3      | 1
---------------
1      | 2
---------------
2      | 2
---------------
```

How to find post with id = 2 by array of userIDs = [1,2]?

**UPD.** I dont know post ID, I need to find it. 2 was just an example what I want to get. I need to find post related to exact set of associated objects via junction table.

Trying to use smth like that, but not sure if it's the best way

```
select p.id from posts as p
inner join userpost as up on up.post_id = p.id
inner join users as u on up.user_id = u.id
where u.id in $(user_array);
```

Thank you

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: @Fermin as I'm using mostly ORM, at first I've simply tried to get all users, group userposts by userID, and compare group results to id's arays, however got some ORM build-in methods limitation. So finding the way to do it with plain SQL. I'll update my answer soon, hope some kind of misunderstanding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following code will do the job you want:

```
Select 
  posts.id
  posts.text
From 
  posts
Where 
  posts.id in (select PostID from userposts where UserID in (1,2))
```

This will return every post which is added by users 1 or 2. You can change these values to be array or another select.